# Flexbox vertical alignment - items not completly central

Tags: html, css, flexbox, pug, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to create header, were on one side there is logo with navigation and on other side options for user. But I run into problem - items on opposite sides is not completly centered. I tried removing padding but results stayed the same.

Any ideas how to fix it?

```
header
  nav
    img(src="assets/img/logo.png").logo
    div.divider
    ul
      li: a(href="") Link
      li: a(href="") Link
      li: a(href="") Link
      li: a(href="") Link
  div.options
    div.leagues-dropdown Option
    div.date-picker Option
    div.search Option
    div.account Option
```

And SASS

```
header
    height: 67px
    padding: 0 25px
    display: flex
    justify-content: space-between
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D2D2D2
    align-items: center

    .logo
        width: 67px
        height: 15px
        padding-right: 25px

    .divider
        height: 67px
        border-left: 1px solid #D2D2D2
        padding-right: 25px

    nav
        display: flex
        align-items: center

        a
            opacity: 0.55
            font-family: OpenSans-Bold
            font-size: 12px
            color: #000000
            text-transform: uppercase
            text-decoration: none

        ul
            display: flex
            li
                padding: 0 10px

    .options
        display: flex
        align-items: center

        div
            padding: 0 10px
            opacity: 0.55
            font-family: OpenSans-Bold
            font-size: 12px
            color: #000000
            text-transform: uppercase
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZGeLO

Comment: What do you mean by "items on opposite sides is not completely centered"? How do you want it to look?

Comment: I want both sides to be on the same line http://i.imgur.com/pbxTTDz.png

Comment: Use `display:block` on your `a`elements

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Maybe you know if using this breaks any floats or it doesnt matter, since i'm using flexbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing right, but I would put the link nav with the option nav under the same parent then I would use `display: flex` and `align-items:center` on the parent. This way you are 100% sure that they are on the same line.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think this is not going to work, since i'm using divider, which is the same size as header. But i will try.